# Search the content of an Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel, powershell

I'm looking for a way to browse the content of several hundreds of Excel files to find and remove any trace of an hard-coded user and password.

I was hoping for a function in Powershell but so far I have not found it.

Comment: Where are you with this? You should have a good base with what I propose

Answer (score 2):

You should use a File Scripting Object, [see examples there](http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/filesystemobject-in-vba/)

And combine **Referencing VBIDE Objects**, **Listing All Modules In A Project** and :

**Searching For Text In A Module**

```
Sub SearchCodeModule()
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim FindWhat As String
    Dim SL As Long ' start line
    Dim EL As Long ' end line
    Dim SC As Long ' start column
    Dim EC As Long ' end column
    Dim Found As Boolean

    Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Module1")
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

    FindWhat = "findthis"

    With CodeMod
        SL = 1
        EL = .CountOfLines
        SC = 1
        EC = 255
        Found = .Find(target:=FindWhat, StartLine:=SL, StartColumn:=SC, _
            EndLine:=EL, EndColumn:=EC, _
            wholeword:=True, MatchCase:=False, patternsearch:=False)
        Do Until Found = False
            Debug.Print "Found at: Line: " & CStr(SL) & " Column: " & CStr(SC)
            EL = .CountOfLines
            SC = EC + 1
            EC = 255
            Found = .Find(target:=FindWhat, StartLine:=SL, StartColumn:=SC, _
                EndLine:=EL, EndColumn:=EC, _
                wholeword:=True, MatchCase:=False, patternsearch:=False)
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Source : [cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx)